# Ставится ли запятая перед как: " зарекомендовал как грамотный"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, как

Нужно ли ставить запятую перед как в предложении: "Он зарекомендовал себя как грамотный и квалифицированный сотрудник."?

Comment: @Василина Метка должна отражать тематику вопроса, а не быть случайно взятым словом.

Answer (score 2):

Нет, не ставится,так как союз "как" в данном предложении употребляется в значении "в качестве"

Answer (score 0):

Запятая не нужна, это понятно, не буду повторять.
А вот сам оборот мне почему-то очень не нравится.
Какой-то очень искусственный. Во-первых "зарекомендовать кого-то" никогда не используется, во-вторых, "рекомендовать" - глагол двухвидовой, (что сделал? - "рекомендовал"), зачем ему ещё ничего не значащая приставка в подобной конструкции?

Или я придираюсь?

Comment: Придираетесь, это клише делового и отчасти научного и публицистического стилей:"истребитель танков зарекомендовал себя достаточно эффективным оружием ..."
"он зарекомендовал себя как один из активных и..." .
 "Основательно зарекомендовал себя проект подготовки..."

Comment: Тем не менее примеров без "себя" Вы таки не приводите. Это раз.
И два. Клише - это плохо. От вонных технарей ещё и не то услышишь...

За скобками: "Основательно зарекомендовал" - это вообще песня. Ну ладно бы ещё "хорошо"... "Основательно" это тщательно, глубоко (не поверхностно), методично, вдумчиво, обстоятельно - на крайний случай. А в таком-то контексте оно что значит?

Comment: Наверное, зарекомендовать (что сделать?) можно только себя, но не кого-то, а рекомендовать(что делать? - нсв.) - кого? кому? что? Не совсем понятно, почему tmp отнес глагол "рекомендовал" (что делал?) к св.виду, когда это нсв.вид. Наверное, Вы придираетесь к этой фразе. Она избитая, но часто применяема в лит. и разг. речи. Интересно, когда появилось впервые  словосочетание "зарекомендовать себя"?

Comment: >Не совсем понятно, почему tmp "рекомендовал" (что делал?) к св.виду, 
Я не относил к "св.виду". Я написал, это *двухвидовой* глагол.

Comment: Нормальный глагол. В словарях тоже есть. У Ожегова: ЗАРЕКОМЕНДОВА́ТЬ совер.: зарекомендовать себя кем проявить себя с какой-н. (обычно хорошей) стороны. Зарекомендовать себя хорошим работником.

Comment: И "основательно" можно себя зарекомендовать - в значении "прочно, крепко". Фраза не моя, но мне понятна:"Как сценарист Гилрой зарекомендовал себя давно и основательно, а после просмотра "Майкла Клейтона" можно утверждать, что он показал себя еще и как режиссер, смело..." 

"Чтобы не стать фирмой-однодневкой, нам нужно было основательно (прочно)зарекомендовать себя(проявить свои хорошие качества) на рынке мебели"

А клише - это не плохо, а свидетельство стилевой принадлежности.Вот если канцеляризмы употреблять в бытовом разговоре - это плохо. А здесь книжный текст. Всё нормально.

Comment: " Тем не менее примеров без "себя" Вы таки не приводите"- без "себя" - это уже не клише.Клише - готовое выражение, шаблон.